# Game freezes after the button is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Hello Im making a start button for my game, but when I press it, the game freezes for 3-4  seconds then loads the next scene. I just want to make it wait 1 and then switch the scene.

```
IEnumerator Play(){
    isPressed = true;
    sprite.enabled = false;
    click = true;
    myAudio.Play();
    particle.Play();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("dupa menu1");
}
 public void pressButt(){
    StartCoroutine(Play());
   
}
```

I put the pressButt variable on the UI button, On Click()

Thanks

Comment: I don't the real ideia about what structure you are using but, based in your description i think SceneManager.LoadScene("dupa menu1"); is being loaded in runtime. So, the problem is, everything you load in runtime will take time to be loaded into your game. So, my sugestion is what about load all scenes you will need at game startup and based on achivements and game unlocks just call required scenes allready loaded.

Comment: @integer for larger projects this can very fast overload the memory ... you usually only want to have loaded what you actually need .. of course it depends on the individual use case and there is always this trade-off between memory usage vs loading delays

Comment: @derHugo but its a small game, i want to switch between a menu scene to a scene that contains only a canvas and 1 image and 2 text boxes. But when I switch from the canvas scene to the actual game scene it didn't freeze

Answer (score 0):

your logic design is incorrect bec the scene need time to load after WaitForSeconds(1), it wont start immediately after 1 sec.

The best way to do something similar or work around is using [SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is "incorrect" .. it is just synchronous and therefore will freeze a moment. Also using `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` will still take the same time until the scene is loaded .. this just solves some of the freezing ;)